Is there a management API for Azure Bot Services?
I already have the Facebook page ID and token provided by the client. How can I programmatically add them to the Facebook channel in the Microsoft Bot Framework using a POST request?
I've marked the location to add the Facebook page in red. I tried using the Management API, but I received a 403 error, which makes me feel like it's not the right solution. I followed the documentation, but I didn't get the expected outcome

this is my current code which led to 403 and as I said i don't believe its the solution
import { HttpService } from '@nestjs/axios';
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ConfigService } from '@nestjs/config';
import { ClientSecretCredential } from '@azure/identity';

@Injectable()
export class AzureService {
  constructor(
    private configService: ConfigService,
    private httpService: HttpService
  ) {}

  async addFacebookPage(pageAccessToken: string, pageId: string) {
    const botEndpoint = 'https://management.azure.com';
    const botResourcePath = `/subscriptions/${this.configService.get('AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION_ID')}/resourceGroups/${this.configService.get('AZURE_RESOURCE_GROUP')}/providers/Microsoft.BotService/botServices/${this.configService.get('AZURE_BOT_NAME')}/channels/FacebookChannel`;

    const payload = {
      properties: {
        pageAccessToken: pageAccessToken,
        pageId,
      },
    };

    const url = `${botEndpoint}${botResourcePath}?api-version=2018-07-12`;

    // Get the Azure Bot token using ClientSecretCredential
    const token = await this.getBotToken();
    const headers = {
      Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
    };

    try {
      const response = await this.httpService.axiosRef.put(url, payload, { headers });
      return response.data;
    } catch (error) {
      throw new Error(`Failed to add page to azure : ${error.message}`);
    }
  }

  private async getBotToken(): Promise<string> {
    // Using ClientSecretCredential from @azure/identity to get the access token
    const tenantId = this.configService.get<string>('AZURE_TENANT_ID');
    const clientId = this.configService.get<string>('MICROSOFT_APP_ID');
    const clientSecret = this.configService.get<string>('MICROSOFT_APP_PASSWORD');

    const credential = new ClientSecretCredential(tenantId, clientId, clientSecret);

    try {
      const tokenResponse = await credential.getToken('https://management.azure.com/.default');
      console.log('Token successfully retrieved:', tokenResponse.token); // Debugging only

      return tokenResponse.token; // Return the access token
    } catch (error) {
      throw new Error(`Failed to get bot token for azure: ${error.message}`);
    }
  }
}


Can you share the documentation which you followed?


I've marked the location to add the Facebook page in red. I tried using the Management API, but I received a 403 error.

The 403 error occurs due to when attempting to add a Facebook page to your Azure Bot Service indicates a permissions issue or an incorrect configuration. Check the app as proper permission to add the Facebook channel with page id.
To add Facebook channel the app needs Contributor role at resource group level.
You can use the below command to list the roles of app registration and add the contributor role to the resource group.
Command:
# Check current roles
az role assignment list --assignee <CLIENT_ID> -all

# Assign Contributor role if missing
az role assignment create \
  --assignee <CLIENT_ID> \
  --role Contributor \
  --scope /subscriptions/<SUBSCRIPTION_ID>/resourceGroups/<RESOURCE_GROUP>

Output:
zzzz [ ~ ]$ az role assignment list --assignee 'clientid' --all
[
  {
    "condition": null,
    "conditionVersion": null,
    "createdBy": "6xxx",
    "createdOn": "xxx",
    "delegatedManagedIdentityResourceId": null,
    "description": null,
    "id": "/subscriptions/xxx/resourceGroups/xx/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/venkat326123/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments/fd56747e-1470-4433-a242-33acfbb78edc",
    "name": "xxxx",
    "principalId": "xxx",
    "principalName": "xxx",
    "principalType": "ServicePrincipal",
    "resourceGroup": "xxx",
    "roleDefinitionId": "/subscriptions/xxxxx/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions/xxxx",
    "roleDefinitionName": "Storage Blob Data Contributor",
    "scope": "/subscriptions/xxx/resourceGroups/xxxx/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/venkat326123",
    "type": "Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments",
    "updatedBy": "63682e3e-bbd6-444f-9d84-6f4d45d59218",
    "updatedOn": "2024-12-02T07:38:50.043262+00:00"
  }
]
venkatesan [ ~ ]$ az role assignment create --assignee <CLIENT_ID> --role Contributor --scope /subscriptions/<SUBSCRIPTION_ID>/resourceGroups/<RESOURCE_GROUP>
{
  "condition": null,
  "conditionVersion": null,
  "createdBy": null,
  "createdOn": "2024-12-02T07:42:40.962255+00:00",
  "delegatedManagedIdentityResourceId": null,
  "description": null,
  "id": "/subscriptions/xxx/resourceGroups/xxx/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments/61045da3-fd76-4fef-8670-fe74bd620ab5",
  "name": "xxxx",
  "principalId": "375760b6-497c-4606-b0fe-98eeb25af615",
  "principalType": "xxx",
  "resourceGroup": "xxx",
  "roleDefinitionId": "/subscriptions/bxxxx/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions/xxxxc",
  "scope": "/subscriptions/xx/resourceGroupsxxxg",
  "type": "Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments",
  "updatedBy": "63682e3e-bbd6-444f-9d84-6f4d45d59218",
  "updatedOn": "2024-12-02T07:42:42.547743+00:00"
}

Portal:

Portal:

Now, you can use the same code to add the Facebook channel with pageId using Microsoft Bot Framework using a POST request.
